# How do I use sensitive data in a unit test in VSTS?

Tags: c#, credentials, xunit, azure-pipelines-build-task

I don't want to check in any username and passwords into my repository obviously.

So how do I handle my *tests* requiring private information? I can just `.gitignore` my private XML file locally, but how do I supply this information in a VSTS .NET Core Test task?

I need to *somehow* (preferably in a clean way) get access to a few properties. It doesn't need to be an XML file necessarily.

Comment: You mean credentials to a production or non-production system? What harm can they do if lost?

Comment: are you sure it's a unit test btw?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's a small hobby project. I can't afford a test environment. The intent is to test a small section of network code by connecting to a server and doing something nobody will notice. Specifically, it's a game server admin project and I'm just going to tell a non-existent player hello :).

Comment: If you mean connecting to a web service using that username and password, then you shouldn't do that in a unit test because unit tests aren't supposed to do that.

Comment: It sounds like you're performing an integration test, not a unit test. Integration tests like this are fine but shouldn't be confused with unit tests. And if it's simply a matter of sending data to a 'remote' service, why not have the service running locally and use the localhost address? This sends the packet through the stack as if it were a remote host, meeting your requirements.

Comment: @DanielleSummers The service (game servers) is proprietary and not available for yourself to host. Otherwise I'd do that.
And yeah this might be more fitting as an integration test. I must admit I've never done integration tests before so I wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn’t the option to specify/override the parameters for custom/user data, through dotnet test.

You can store the sensitive data in the **secret variable** of vsts build/release and override the value in the file (e.g. XML) with that variable before **donet test task** through Token replace task (e.g. [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens))

On the other hand, you may try it with **Visual Studio Test task** with runsettings:

VSTest: `Specify Location`

Path to vstest.console.exe: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform`

Other console options: `/framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0"`

Override TestRun Parameters:`xxxx`

Related article: [Supplying Run Time Parameters to Tests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/09/04/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/)

Comment: The secret variable and token replace plugin work flawlessly! I also used `git update-index --assume-unchanged MyFile.xml` to be able to run tests locally. And finding the correct directory with my file wasn't easy either but it works both in VSTS and locally now. Awesome :D.